# how to write onblur and onfocus event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question**:

```
 <body onload="setBlurFocus()">   
     <form method="POST" action="#">   
              <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" />
              <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" />
              <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /> 
        </form> 
    </body>
```

I **wrote** :

```
function setBlurFocus () {
    var user_input = document.getElementById('id_username');
    var email = document.getElementById('id_email');
    var password = document.getElementById('id_password');
    user_input.onblur = userSetBlur();
    email.onblur = emailSetBlur();
    password.onblur = passSetBlur();
    user_input.onfocus = function() {
            document.getElementById('id_username').value = ''   
        }
    email.onfocus = function() {
            document.getElementById('id_email').value = ''  
        }
    password.onfocus = function() {
            document.getElementById('id_password').value = ''   
        }

}

function userSetBlur() {
    document.getElementById('id_username').value = 'Username'
}
function emailSetBlur() {
    document.getElementById('id_email').value = 'Email'
}

function passSetBlur() {
    document.getElementById('id_password').value = 'Password'
}
```

**Question?**
How to `generalize` or `optimized` this code?

Comment: Why can you not use onblur and onfocus in that way? It seems like the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always attach the methods in JavaScript:

```
function setBlurFocus() {
    var user_input = document.getElementById('id_username');
    user_input.onblur = someFunction;
    // or with an anonymous function:
    user_input.onfocus = function() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Read more about [*traditional event handling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) and [events in general](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

---

**Further explanation:**

You attached the function `setBlurFocus` to the `load` event of the document. This is correct if you have to access DOM elements with JavaScript. The `load` event is fired when all the elements are created.

If you attach the `setBlurFocus()` to the `blur` event of the `input` field, then the function is only executed when the text box looses focus.

From your question I concluded you don't want set the event handlers in the HTML, but you want to set them form inside the `setBlurFocus` function.

---

**Regarding your update:**

This is wrong:

```
user_input.onblur = userSetBlur();
```

This assigns the *return value* of the function to `onblur`. You want to assign the function itself, so you have to write:

```
 user_input.onblur = userSetBlur;
```

The `()` *calls* the function. You don't want that (in most cases, there are exceptions, see below).

Furthermore, you don't have to use named functions for `onblur` and anonymous functions for `onfocus`. It was just an example, to show you the different possibilities you have. E.g. if you assign an event handler to only one element, then there is no need to define it as extra function. But you have to do this if you want to *reuse* event handlers.

Here is an improved version:

```
function setBlurFocus () {
    var values = ["Username", "Email", "Password"];
    var elements = [
        document.getElementById('id_username'),
        document.getElementById('id_email'),
        document.getElementById('id_password')
    ];

    for(var i = elements.length; i--; ) {
        elements[i].onblur = setValue(values[i]);
        elements[i].onfocus = emptyValue;
    }
}

function setValue(defaultValue) {
    return function(){this.value = defaultValue;};
}

function emptyValue() {
    this.value = '';
}
```

`this` inside the event handlers refers to the element the handler is bound to.

**Note:** Here `setValue` *returns a function*, that is why we call `setValue` in this case (and not just assign it).

**Important note:** This will also reset the values to `Username` etc, if the user entered some data. You have to make sure, that you only reset it if the user has not entered data. Something like:

```
function setValue(defaultValue) {
    return function(){
        if(this.value !== "") {
            this.value = defaultValue;
        }
    };
}
```

and you'd have to define `emptyValue` similar:

```
function emptyValue(defaultValue) {
    return function(){
        if(this.value === defaultValue) {
            this.value = "";
        }
    };
}
```

---

Now that I know what you actually want to do, have also a look at [HTML5's `placeholder` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

Comment: How can I generalized in such a way that I need to write only one method for blur and another for focus for every element.

Comment: Just a little issue: I can set `onfocus="this.blur();"` in `<input type="text">` tag for [this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17319563/1369235). But how do I set it from JavaScript? i.e. what I am missing here? `document.getElementById('txtName').onfocus=this.blur();`

Comment: @hims056: You have to assign a function to `onfocus`: `document.getElementById('txtName').onfocus= function() { this.blur(); };`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. Another way is without using function: `document.getElementById('txtName').onfocus=document.getElementById('txtName').blur;` But the solution given by you is better and less depended.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've tagged it with jquery so this is how to do it in jquery:

```
function setBlurFocus () {
  //do stuff here
} 

$('#id_username').blur(setBlurFocus);
```

or

```
$('#id_username').blur(function(){
    //do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your update**

I using jquery as you tab jquery, the code was bellow , you can check a live sample with this link :

http://jsfiddle.net/e3test/zcGgz/

html code :

```
<form method="POST" action="#">   
             <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /> 
</form>
```

javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    var selector = {
        username: $('#id_username'),
        email: $('#id_email'),
        password: $('#id_password')
    };

    for (var x in selector) {
        selector[x].focus(function(){
           $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('name'));
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it help.