# Use readonly attribute in <input> without changing the cursor

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an `<input>` field with the `readonly` attribute, it still appears with the I-beam text cursor. Is there a way to stop that cursor from showing?

I cant use the `disabled` attribute because `request.getParameter()` does not work on disabled fields.

Comment: How are you building (JSP code? HTML code?) the `<input>`?

Comment: If you want to clarify which cursor you mean, say "mouse cursor" vs "keyboard cursor" or "[pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(graphical_user_interfaces))" vs "[caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)". Both cursors look like an I-beam when in a textfield.

Comment: Just want to add,`request.getParameter()` is not working because if you set the attribute "disabled" to your element like select or input ,It would not be submitted when it is part of a form @Premshankar Tiwari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this markup in your form for text field

`<input type="text" value="test" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" />`

main thing which helps you hide the cursor is onfocus="this.blur()".

Comment: Oh...great...How can I didn't notice this before...works in firefox but in IE it takes time to blur...still a good solution..thanks

Comment: This scenario doesnt work well with IE. I would prefer overriding the cursor in bootstrap CSS and write my CSS pointer property leaving `<input>` as `readonly`.

Answer (score 36):

The idea of `readonly` elements is that you can still read and copy the text, just not edit them. That said, you can change the cursor using [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). This example will match any `input` element with a `readonly` attribute:

```
input[readonly] {
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that...it just shows the respective cursor when you hover...but when you click..the field gets the cursor..

Comment: If it doesnt work, try
    cursor:pointer !important;
This should overright stronger default settings. Ive become more familiar with important the more I work with twitter bootstrap. :|

Comment: @AaronLoften I've found I very rarely have to use `!important` with Bootstrap. I just have to give me selector a higher specificity than theirs. See http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity :)

Comment: I would recommend using `cursor: text;` since you would expect to get the text selection cursor when hovering over text. An editable textarea would give you that.

Answer (score 15):

I did not want to override bootstrap's default styles so I came along with the following solution:

My LESS File:

```
input[readonly] {
    &.default-cursor {
        cursor: default;
    }
}
```

Or in CSS:

```
input[readonly].default-cursor {
    cursor: default;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-xl default-cursor" readonly>
```

Comment: @totas: Thanks a lot! this is best answer.

Answer (score 8):

For people who don't want to have the caret showing at all:

```
input[readonly] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```