# How do I execute my function whenever the input field loses its focus?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, textbox, focus

In Javascript, I want to execute my function whenever the textbox loses its focus. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `onblur` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to write onblur and onfocus event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014710/how-to-write-onblur-and-onfocus-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options

OnFocousOut

```
<input type="text" 
           name="input" 
           value="Lorem"
           onfocusout="yourFunction();" />
```

or
OnBlur

```
 <input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-javascript-when-an-element-loses-focus/

Answer (score 0):

In most of the case I don't use onblur I use onchange method because it will indicate user only if user change the value of text box so i think it's user friendly.

Easiest method is to add your javascript in html tag

```
   <input type = "text" onchange = "yourFunction()">
```

but this is not a good practice. Write your javascript in external file.